# Complex Version of Polynomial Interpolation Uniqueness

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, interpolation

I came across the following, well known, uniqueness result concerning polynomial interpolation, which is sated as follows:

> Let $x_0,x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ be $n+1$ distinct points in $[a,b]$. There exists a unique polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ or less that interpolates $f(x)$ at the points $\{x_i\}$.

My question is twofold:

1. Is there a complex version of the above result? Maybe something like: If $z_0, z_1,\dotsc,z_n$ are distinct points in a closed connected region, then there exists a complex polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ or less that interpolates $f(z)$, where $f(z)$ is holomorphic?
2. If so, where might I be able to find the theorem?

I attempted searching online, but all of the results I came across concern themselves with $\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you!

Comment: This is true because of the [following result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810645/polynomial-of-degree-n-with-n1-zeros/1810662) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857196/can-a-polynomial-of-n-degree-have-n1-distinct-real-roots). Just assume there are 2 polynomials and they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this lemma

> **Lemma**. A polynomial $P(z)$ of degree $n$ with $n+1$ zeros is $P(z)\equiv 0$.

we can **assume that there exists $2$ polynomials** $P_1(z) \ne P_2(z)$ such that $P_1(z_i)=P_2(z_i)=f(z_i), i=0..n$. Both polynomials are of degree $n$ or less. Then we construct the following polynomial
$$P(z)=P_1(z) - P_2(z)$$
which is of degree $n$ or less and has $n+1$ zeros
$$P(z_i)=P_1(z_i) - P_2(z_i)=f(z_i)-f(z_i)=0, i=0..n$$
But according to the lemma above, $P(z)\equiv 0$ or $P_1(z)\equiv P_2(z)$, which contradicts the assumption.